# Hiding a paragraph using mutation in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

i am trying to understand vuex and mutations and actions and i get that to change the state, you need to use a mutation but in practical it seems like maybe i am doing something wrong or i don't understand it well.

I am trying to hide this paragraph using a mutation from the store. I am using this real basic code to understand the concept of mutation.

```
  <template>
  <p v-if="this.$store.state.true">Hide this using Vuex </p>
  <v-btn @click="true = !true"> Click Me </v-btn>
  </template>
```

In my store. JS file

```
state : {
    true: false
  }

 mutations: {
    How would i go about creating a mutation????
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mutations: {
    TOGGLE_TRUE (state) {
        state.true = !state.true
    }
}

<v-btn @click="$store.commit('TOGGLE_TRUE')"> Click Me </v-btn>
```

I usually write mutations with uppercase snakecase, but you can change it to lowercase. It is case sensitive.

To trigger a mutation, use `commit` and the mutation name as parameter.
You can also pass an extra variable to commit 2nd parameter e.g:

```
$store.commit('TOGGLE_TRUE', true)

TOGGLE_TRUE (state, bool) {
    state.true = bool
}
```

and if you want to pass more data, use object and ES6 tree shaking

```
person = {name: 'johndoe', age: 30}
$store.commit('SET_PERSON', person)

SET_PERSON (state, {name, age}) {
    state.name = name
    state.age = age
}
```

p.s You should find a better self-explanatory state name instead of just 'true', something like 'showParagraph' will do.

Comment: why do you use uppercase when naming your mutations ... is there a logic reason behind it or just to avoid overwriting / case sensitive and something like that ?

Comment: @SirDad it was when I first learning vuex, I was also searching about naming convention, and stumbled upon question like https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-are-your-vuex-best-practice-recommendations/1197 and some other questions as well. And when using vuex namespaced modules, it's easier to look at first glance because the function name is in uppercase and the module name is camelCase.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And yes i changed the state variable lol